# Image on Navbar makes navigation menu expands

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a code when i load an image first of all my navbar expands and take too much space on, how i can avoid such?
Secondly when i load an image as mentioned above my links to sections does not work properly as it does not take me to the top of section but bit lower because of size of navbar.

Any suggestions or help please?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/images/osamatraders.svg" width="60" alt="">
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler bg-light " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav"><span
                    class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="nav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-light text-uppercase font-weight-bold px-3" href="#aboutus">About
                            Us</a></li>
```

Comment: Give ``navbar-brand`` to the image not the a tag.

Comment: Sorry what you mean by above Amirreza?

Comment: ``<a href="#"><img src="foo"  class="navbar-brand"></a>``

Comment: Thanks it did not changed anything.